# how save web service in a variable and to manipulate her

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

it wanted a help to optimize my code. I am new in the programming and think that it is not necessary to do a different method for every every web service, it is possible to be possible that a web service could avoid in a variable and to manipulate her.

I have two methods which it does the same function the only thing that changes is the web service

this is mi code:

```
public class Notificaciones
{
    private WSPradera.ServicioSoapClient WPredial = new WSPradera.ServicioSoapClient();
    private WSApartado.ServicioSoapClient WPredialApartado = new WSApartado.ServicioSoapClient();
    private WSCopacabana.ServicioSoapClient WPredialCopacabana = new WSCopacabana.ServicioSoapClient();
    private WSSanPedroMilagros.ServicioSoapClient WPredialSanPedroMilagros = new WSSanPedroMilagros.ServicioSoapClient();

public Notificaciones(PropiedadesPSE obj)
{
   this.objPropiedades = obj;
}

#region Apartadó
public bool Apartado()
{
   bool flag = true;
   try
   {
       if (this.objPropiedades.TransactionStatus != "A")
       {
           return flag;
       }
       XElement xml = new XElement("referencia", this.objPropiedades.Numfactura);
       XElement notificarPago = this.WPredialApartado.GetNotificarPago(xml);
       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cliente));
       StringReader textReader = new StringReader(notificarPago.ToString());
       cliente cliente = (cliente)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            if (cliente.ToString() != "")
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.LogException(Regex.Replace(string.Concat(new object[] { exception.Message, " ", exception.InnerException, " ", exception.StackTrace }), @"\t|\n|\r", "").Replace("'", ""));
            throw exception;
        }
        return flag;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Copacabana
    public bool Copacabana()
    {
        bool flag = true;
        try
        {
            if (this.objPropiedades.TransactionStatus != "A")
            {
                return flag;
            }
            XElement xml = new XElement("referencia", this.objPropiedades.Numfactura);
            XElement notificarPago = this.WPredialCopacabana.GetNotificarPago(xml);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cliente));
            StringReader textReader = new StringReader(notificarPago.ToString());
            cliente cliente = (cliente)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            if (cliente.ToString() != "")
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.LogException(Regex.Replace(string.Concat(new object[] { exception.Message, " ", exception.InnerException, " ", exception.StackTrace }), @"\t|\n|\r", "").Replace("'", ""));
            throw exception;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most (all? - are there any differences?) of that logic looks identical so you could move it to another method and call that

Comment: What I want is to have the same method but this one changes line of code to a variable: XElement notificarPago = this.WPredialCopacabana.GetNotificarPago(xml);
In order that it is dynamic.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not clear on what you want the same line (XElement notificarPago = this.WPredialCopacabana.GetNotificarPago(xml)) appears in both Apartado and Copacabana (and both Apartado and Copacabana seem t be identical). On the face of it you don't need both Apartado and Copacabana if they are the same but I don't see what it is you want to make dynamic, the values which create 'xml'?